# How to make an Animate plot more smooth

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, animation

I am using Animate to animate the result of a system of coupled differential equations as I vary an initial condition A:

```
l = 1.0;
m = 1.0;
g = 10.0;
h = 10;
u = 0.05;    
Animate[sol3 = 
      NDSolve[{m*
          x''[t] == ((((m*g)/l)*(l/2 - (x[t]))*k[t]*
             u) - (((m*g)/l)*(l/2 + (x[t])))*j[t]*u), 
        WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, {Tn[t] -> t, V0[t] -> Abs[x'[t]]}], 
        WhenEvent[
         t == Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
             4) + ((3.0*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) + 0.01, 
         x'[t] -> 
          x'[t]*(1 - (((V0[t] + 1)*h*u)/(20*(1 + 1.2*V0[t])*Abs[x'[t]]*2*
                 l)))], WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, r[t] -> Abs[x[t]]], 
        x[0] == A, x'[0] == 0, V0[0] == 0, Tn[0] == 0, 
        a[t] == Piecewise[{{0, 
            Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
                4) + ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) > t > 
             Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
                4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}, {1, 
            t < Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
                4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}, {1, 
            t > Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
                4) + ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}}], 
        WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, b[t] -> 1], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, b[t] -> 0], 
        WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, c[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, c[t] -> 1], 
        d[t] == a[t] + b[t], f[t] == a[t] + c[t], k[t] == Tanh[100*d[t]], 
        j[t] == Tanh[100*f[t]]}, {a, x, Tn, V0, b, c, d, f, k, j, r}, {t, 
        0, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {Tn, V0, b, c, r}]; 
     Plot[x[t] /. sol3[[1]], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All], {A, 0.03, 
      0.045}]
```

However, the result I obtain by doing this is an extremely sloppy and non smooth animation. What could I do to make this animation smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a complicated calculation for an animation, you get smoother plots with `ListAnimate` because you cache the plots first.

```
l = 1.0;
m = 1.0;
g = 10.0;
h = 10;
u = 0.05;

sol3 := NDSolve[{m*
     x''[t] == ((((m*g)/l)*(l/2 - (x[t]))*k[t]*
        u) - (((m*g)/l)*(l/2 + (x[t])))*j[t]*u), 
   WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, {Tn[t] -> t, V0[t] -> Abs[x'[t]]}], 
   WhenEvent[
    t == Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
        4) + ((3.0*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) + 0.01, 
    x'[t] -> 
     x'[t]*(1 - (((V0[t] + 1)*h*u)/(20*(1 + 1.2*V0[t])*Abs[x'[t]]*2*
            l)))], WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, r[t] -> Abs[x[t]]], 
   x[0] == A, x'[0] == 0, V0[0] == 0, Tn[0] == 0, 
   a[t] == Piecewise[{{0, 
       Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
           4) + ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) > t > 
        Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
           4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}, {1, 
       t < Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
           4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}, {1, 
       t > Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/
           4) + ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}}], 
   WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, b[t] -> 1], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, b[t] -> 0], 
   WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, c[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, c[t] -> 1], 
   d[t] == a[t] + b[t], f[t] == a[t] + c[t], k[t] == Tanh[100*d[t]], 
   j[t] == Tanh[100*f[t]]}, {a, x, Tn, V0, b, c, d, f, k, j, r}, {t, 
   0, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {Tn, V0, b, c, r}]

tb = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol3[[1]]], {t, 0, 100}, 
    PlotRange -> {-.4, .4}], {A, 0.03, 0.045, .0002}];

ListAnimate[tb]
```

[image]

Also, when you use `PlotRange->All` with an animation, the scale adjusts itself with each frame.  It is better to use a fixed `PlotRange`.  Notice I also used `:=` because `NDSolve` requires all variables to be defined, and `A` is not defined until the `Plot` command.  This method may use more memory than the `Animate` command because each frame is cached in advance, but it animates much smoother than `Animate` which must calculate each frame as it is plotting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) to create a list of parametric interpolation functions using `A` as the parameter:

```
pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{m*x''[t] == ((((m*g)/l)*(l/2 - (x[t]))*k[t]* u) - 
      (((m*g)/l)*(l/2 + (x[t])))*j[t]*u), 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, {Tn[t] -> t, V0[t] -> Abs[x'[t]]}], 
    WhenEvent[t == Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/4) +
     ((3.0*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) + 0.01, 
     x'[t] ->  x'[t]*(1 - (((V0[t] + 1)*h*u)/(20*(1 + 1.2*V0[t])*Abs[x'[t]]*2* l)))], 
    WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, r[t] -> Abs[x[t]]], 
    x[0] == A, x'[0] == 0, V0[0] == 0, Tn[0] == 0, 
    a[t] == Piecewise[{{0, Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/4) + 
       ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t]))) > t > Tn[t] +
       ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))},
      {1, t < Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/ 4) - ((1*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}, 
      {1, t > Tn[t] + ((3.14*(2*l/(u*g))^0.5)/4) +
        ((3*V0[t]*h)/(4*g*(l/2 - r[t])))}}], 
    WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, b[t] -> 1], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, b[t] -> 0], 
    WhenEvent[x[t] <= 0, c[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, c[t] -> 1], 
    d[t] == a[t] + b[t], f[t] == a[t] + c[t], k[t] == Tanh[100*d[t]], 
    j[t] == Tanh[100*f[t]]},
    {a, x, Tn, V0, b, c, d, f, k, j, r}, 
    {t, 0, 100}, 
    {A}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> {Tn, V0, b, c, r}];
```

it is impossible to distinguish the functions when you plot  all 11 functions together:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@Through@pndsv[A][t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {a, x, Tn, V0, b, c, d, f, k, j, r}], 
 {A, 0.03, 0.045}]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to plot the functions separately in grid:'

```
Animate[GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[#, 4, 4, 1, {}] &@
   MapThread[Plot[#@t, {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2], 
      PlotLabel -> #3, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Small] &,
    {pndsv[A], Range[11], {a, x, Tn, V0, b, c, d, f, k, j, r}}]], 
  {A, 0.03, 0.045, 0.0025}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image]